# Bootstrap Scrollspy Incorrect Highlighting

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I have a WordPress site that integrates bootstrap scrollspy. Scrollspy is activated when you scroll but it highlights the first two items incorrectly in the navbar. It seems there is an offset problem due to the first content box being bigger than the other ones, but I have added an offset in the body tag and through `jQuery('.navbar').scrollspy()`. I also added `padding-top: 100px` to the first content box on the page. None of these solutions work. What am I missing here?

[The working page](http://dev.propertyregistration.com)

Comment: I'll bet is has something to do with your "nicescroll" plugin, not bootstrap scrollspy.

Comment: @davidkonrad Nope just disabled it and still the same.

Comment: Hey @Daniel. What browser are you testing in? I have tried with chrome  / ubuntu, and I ensure you it works. The correct items are highlighted when you are scrolling. If you use IE8, you should add html5.js.

Comment: @davidkonrad The first two items on the navbar does not highlight correctly. Because the height of the first content box is bigger than the others, it is not recognizing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `ScrollSpy` is bind to the element with data attribute `data-spy="scroll"` (in this case `body` element), but as there are many images and contents loading after ready is event is already fired.

I would suggest to use [javascript api](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-usage) of the scrollspy to refresh the offsets and targets calculated using refresh method as demonstrated in the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(updateScrollSpy, 1000);
});
function updateScrollSpy() {
    jQuery('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = jQuery(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    });
}
</script>
```

Also, on "Key Advantage" internal id link is not provided so it is redirect to the link given.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Adding `jQuery(document).ready()` function to the refresh fixed it.